# How to read a file of extension .dat in python and extract data from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, serial-port, pyserial

[image: i want the values from 01 10 60 upto 7f 00 00 and after that i want from 02 10 60 and so on..][image: The hex values at the center i want only those i dont want the left and right side values]Hello everyone!
I am currently working on a project and i need to automate the things on it using file handling..there is a file in '.dat' format and i want to extract the data from it..the data present in that is in the form of hex..and by getting these hex values i need to perform serial port communication..i can access this dat file from a tool named hex editor and can see the values from it..but the problem is that i do not want the complete data from that file i need to extract it in segments..i tried to read it but it reads it completely and i got some garbage values also in the output..

i will try to upload a screenshot of the hex editor and the values which i want to extract from it..so please antbody help me out in this

Comment: Dat file can data anywhere from text to movie. Whats the source of dat file? Where's the *garbage* from? Is there any pattern to what should be kept and what should be discarded?

Comment: @SuvenPandey hello sir..actually these are the files which contain database of some route information..i am working on a project of display systems in buses..so this dat file contains the data of some routes which is created through a GUI..if i will send the hex values serially through com port then i will be able to display the message through it..(i am creating a testbench environment through which i can test for bugs and errors)..

Comment: if i copy paste these values into my notepad file and then read these values through my python program which i had created i am able to get the results but this time i want it to automate it completely means i want that i can directly access these hex values from my dat file.

Comment: You might want to include a part of input(text instead of image), what parts you need to extract.

Comment: Also I dont know which hex-editor you are referring to but I think data on the right may be decoded text and not actual file content so why not use `readline`.

Comment: sir i have added an image above

Comment: yes sir it can be a decoded text but as per now its look like a garbage content for me as i want only the hex values mentioned above in the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your .dat file in binary mode, access the data as per your need.
Use 'rb' parameters in open() method for *reading* in *binary* mode.

```
with open('input.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()  # complete binary data will be available in 'data'
    first_byte = data[0]  # access individual byte like this
    second_byte = data[1]
    send_uart(data[:10])  # Send first 10 bytes
```

Comment: in case if there is a data of length 500 bytes then?

Comment: @AkshatPant data[:500]? I didn't get your concern.

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. i think its working now..will get back to you if stuck in between..cheers!!